# Link between the zeros of a function and its derivative.

Tags: derivatives, roots

Suppose I have a polynomial of.degree 5 in Q[x]. If it has 4 or 5 real roots, why does that imply that its derivative has at least 3 real roots?

Comment: Because to achieve four roots, the polynomial must have four alternating decreasing and increasing sections, forming three extrema between them. And similarly, the second derivative will have at least two roots...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Between any two real roots is a maximum or minimum. At each of these extrema, the derivative has a root.